# Cross origin error on saving data in MongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am creating `MERN` stack app and trying to save data using `axios` library.I have added `Cors` dependency on server side some like this.

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(require('./routes/saveData.js'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port,() => {

     console.log(`Server is running on ${port}.`);
});
```

**ERROR**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:5000/save' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Someone please let me know how should I resolve this error.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: thought i would check all angles...did you restart the services after adding the cors module?

Comment: Yes I am using concurrently to start node and react server simultaneously.

Comment: be sure to include the "http://" part before "localhost" in axios and add this: app.options('*', cors()); just below app.use(cors())

Comment: Ohhh, got that thanks @Paolo I was missing `http://`.